# What makes Lua tables key order be undeterministic?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I know that, in Lua, table keys are not preserved in order of creation. So far I thought it'd be due to the internal implementation which might continuosly rearrange the tree nodes in order to improve performance. However, I don't understand why the following snippet doesn't dump the same result even if it's executed in independent runs (e.g. running `lua` interpreter for each run):

```
-- Example script
local t = {a = 1, b = 2}
for k,v in pairs(t) do
  print(k,v)
end
```

Sometimes the code above dumps either:

```
a   1
b   2
```

or:

```
b   2
a   1
```

How is it possible that, with so few lines (in which determinism seems obvious), the interpreter dumps different results? What makes keys order random here? Is the order random at table's creation or at table's iteration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A table (associative array) is used for lookup by key and as such does not have well-defined order when iterating through it.  [Notes on the Implementation of Lua 5.3](https://poga.github.io/lua53-notes/table.html)
is a good overview of how Lua implements the table data structure.  I.e. hash table.  If an adversary can trigger a (key) collision the hash table goes from O(1) insert performance to O(n) per operation, and for if you do that n operations you get O(n^2) behavior.  Therefor, it's [desirable](https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/issues/168) to use a hash function which behavior an adversary cannot predict.  One way to do that is using a randomized seed as part of the hash function:

```
lstate.h: typedef struct global_State {
...
lstate.h: unsigned int seed;  /* randomized seed for hashes */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the answer I expected to get! This approach of randomizing the hash function is pretty clever!

Comment: This random hash seed results in varying performance over successive runs of the same code. It's particularly noticeable on low power embedded devices. I wish it was possible to turn it off.

Comment: @MattSephton Have you isolated that behavior to tables specifically?  Any operations in particular?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, we have. I'm developing for Playdate (ARM STM32F7) and wrote a benchmark suite to test each revision of the SDK because I'm pushing performance ceiling. Variation is up to 10% on multiple runs of the same code, across all tests. Everything is a table in Lua, isn't it? Playdate SDK developer tracked it down to the random hash seed. By building a custom Lua that removed the random hash seed and uses a hard coded seed, runs are pretty much identical every time. Not sure about the long-term feasibility of using that custom Lua version. HTH! Find me on Playdate Devforum.

Comment: @MattSephton With a fixed seed, as you probably know, an adversary may be able to find a particular bad key, and hammer it for O(n) instead of the expected O(k) run-time.  If that access pattern is in a loop you end up with O(n^2) which hurt.  I have been on the receiving end of a DoS in our case against Ruby.

Comment: @AllanWind Of course, I understand why they're using the random hash seed. That's why I queried the feasibility of using a fixed seed build of Lua. Playdate is an offline embedded system so perhaps it's less of a risk there? That's a decision for those more expert than myself. All I know is the random hash seed causes variable performance on such low power embedded devices.